# How to easily pick properties of a type in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm relatively new to Flow and trying to wrap my head around how to type the models in my app.

Let's say I have a model named `Car` that is modeled like so:

```
type Car = {
  id: string,
  make: string,
  model: string,
  owner?: ?{ name: string }
};
```

Now let's say my app is going to create an object that is a car, but since it has yet to be saved, it does not have the otherwise required `id` property:

```
const newCar = {
  make: 'Honda',
  model 'Accord',
};
```

Is there a way to easily select multiple properties of `Car` to assign to `newCar`?

Something like:

`const newCar: $Pick<Car, ['make', 'model']>;`?

Or is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
type Car = {
  id: string,
  make: string,
  model: string,
  owner?: ?{ name: string }
};

const newCar: $Diff<Car, { id: string }> = {
  make: 'Honda',
  model: 'Accord'
}
```

[FLOW TRY](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwghgJygXigbwFBSgSwCYBcUAzsAjgHYDmANFlALZwDWERp51d2DA9nhAA27MpVr1eAdwoQEAfiJy0UCnAZsSo6lAC+GHQG4MGAMa8KpFREnwERACQARHADMXAHls10uQps5UugB8KOj0TKxEAOQAEuZ4cFHcjPxC0QCCJmYIeFH6QA)

Another approach is pretty similar (but I think the first method makes intentions clearer):

```
const newCar: { ...Car, id?: string } = {
  make: 'Honda',
  model: 'Accord'
}
```

This works pretty well when all you need is to remove the `id`. When you start removing more fields, this can become cumbersome.

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea you could use the spread operator with types :)

Answer (score 0):

Using intersection types you could specify a base type and a more specific version for the saved instance.

```
type UnsavedCar = {
  make: string,
  model: string,
  owner?: ?{ name: string }
}

type Car = UnsavedCar & {
  id: string;
}
```

Which also works quite well in functions such as:

```
function saveCar(car: UnsavedCar): Car { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: The problem is that this results in an explosion of types as the number properties grows (and consequently, so do the "sub" types I need)